# Why SQLite index is not speed up query?

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite, indexing

I wrote this query:

```
INSERT INTO KeysTable (KeyText, Id)
SELECT KeyText as BKT, KeysTable.ID as CID FROM KeysTable
INNER JOIN StatTable ON KeysTable.ID = StatTable.Key_ID
WHERE StatTable.StatCommandCode = 4 AND 
EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM StatTable WHERE StatCommandCode = 4 AND StatTable.Key_ID = CID);
```

I know that removing the condition

```
AND StatTable.Key_ID = CID
```

would make the query very fast. Also if I replace it with

```
AND StatTable.Key_ID = 444 // (444 - random static number)
```

the query will be very fast too. Both the columns in this condition are indexed:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS StatsIndex ON StatTable (Key_ID);
```

and in **KeysTable** the **ID** column is primary key. Why doesn't the index improve perfomance in this case?

*Thanks for answers and sorry for my bad english :(.*

Comment: What's the use of that `EXISTS` subquery?

Comment: Are both fields the same type (INT? CHAR?)?

Comment: That EXISTS subquery seems a bit superfluous since you already have that join, no?

Comment: StatTable.Key_ID and KeysTable.ID had same datatypes: [ID] integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL
//---
[Key_ID] integer NOT NULL

Comment: @ypercube - I believe that its the column `KeysTable.ID`  that the renames on the `SELECT`, don't know if that's valid or not

Comment: @Lamak: That's not valid ANSI SQL (you can't use a Select alias in the WHERE caluse). Not sure if that applies to SQLite.

Comment: @ypercube - Yeah, that's what I meant, I don't know if its valid on SQLite

Comment: @Dmitriy: Then (still wondering how that is not producing an error), you can remove the EXISTS subquery. You already have those conditions in the Join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is no `CID` column in any of the two tables, then the `EXISTS` subquery is useless. Rewrite the statement as:

```
INSERT INTO KeysTable (KeyText, Id)
  SELECT KeyText
       , KeysTable.ID  
  FROM KeysTable
    INNER JOIN StatTable 
      ON KeysTable.ID = StatTable.Key_ID
  WHERE StatTable.StatCommandCode = 4
```

If it is still slow, you can try adding an index on `(StatCommandCode, Key_ID)`

Comment: I'm still buffled as to what this is trying to accomplish. You are inserting some data in the `KeysTable` but these data are already there... What's the point of having identical rows in the table?

Comment: Thanks! Still wondering why I use exists before :) (maybe before I have another subquery - don't know). Exists is useless, you are right.

Comment: @Dmitriy: Can you explain what the Insert statement is trying to do? What's the use of it?

Comment: This insert looks like waste because I cut some fields from table :).